# __setattr__ can override __getattribute__ in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following code, it is from Learning Python published by O'Reilly Media. Why line 3 (`self._name = name`) won't trigger `__getattribute__`? Is it because `__setattr__` overrides it?

```
class Person:                               # Portable: 2.X or 3.X
    def __init__(self, name):               # On [Person()]
        self._name = name                   # Triggers __setattr__!

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):                 # On [obj.any]
                print('get: ' + attr)
                if attr == 'name':                         # Intercept all names
                    attr = '_name'                         # Map to internal name
                return object.__getattribute__(self, attr) # Avoid looping here

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):     # On [obj.any = value]
        print('set: ' + attr)
        if attr == 'name':
            attr = '_name'                  # Set internal name
        self.__dict__[attr] = value         # Avoid looping here
```

Comment: You don't need to get the attribute to set it.

Answer (score 4):

You are **setting** an attribute. Assignment to an attribute always uses `__setattr__`.

`__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` are only consulted when looking up the value of a specific attribute; when setting you are not retrieving a value.

This is not an override; even if `__setattr__` was not defined, the `__getattribute__` method would *not* be consulted.